# Meteor Check if User is Admin

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, server, admin

I have a Meteor App in which I need to set some type of variable for the app if a user is an admin so that I can use that later to show/hide certain elements of the HTML. To figure out if the user is an admin, I have to check an object in the LocalStorage on the device and see if it matches the secret string, which would grant the user admin access. However, I don't want the client to see the secret string. For now, I have a file `server/server.js` which has a function in it like this:

```
function isAdmin(cookie) {
    if(cookie == "secret") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, it seems I can't access that function from my main .js file for the app which I'm using like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    admin = false;
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        cookie = localStorage.getItem("admin");
        admin = isAdmin(cookie);
    }
});
```

I don't know if I'm trying to go about this wrong, all I need it to do is check the localStorage for a cookie each time the site is loaded by a client and compare it to the secret string, and then set a variable indicating whether the user is an admin which I can use in the rest of the app. I also need it to be secure so the client cannot just set the variable or anything else to be an admin.

Comment: In your approach the code is on the client, the secret is on the client in a cookie, and the matching secret is also in your aforementioned client code. You've even named the function `isAdmin` to make it easier to find. There is no security there.

Comment: That is why I'm trying to figure out the correct way to do this.

Comment: As @adlen answered, alanning:roles is a good place to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) package is exactly what you need,

To add this package, execute this command:

```
meteor add alanning:roles
```

You can add roles to users like this:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(someUserId, 'super-admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP)
```

and then you can verify if a user has a role like this:

```
if (Roles.userIsInRole(someUserId, ['super-admin'], 'real-madrid.com')) {

  // if a user has the 'super-admin' role he will be able to access here

}
```